# iFrame redirecting homepage issue on mobile

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, redirect, iframe, mobile

I am creating my portfolio using a Bootstrap template (Freelancer). I have an iFrame embed that displays an e-catalog (located in a pop-up lightbox). For some reason when opening my website on a smartphone device, the page redirects automatically to the fullscreen version of the iFrame website without any prompting or touching. I've tried the 'sandbox' tag and it does not seem to work, but perhaps I am using it wrong. To clarify, the site/iFrame embed loads fine on desktop, but on mobile it redirects the homepage.

This is the iFrame code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.zoomcatalog.com/catalogs/kts-spring-2014/" width="100%" height="630px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

The website is http://www.danieltomasku.net

Do I need to add some JavaScript to prevent the window from opening automatically? If so, how do I implement this? Should 'sandboxing' have worked? Should I put a div around the iFrame?

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need more info/code. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, sandboxing might help – although you should check with the owner of that page whether they _want_ you to frame their site first.

Answer (score 1):

The site you are opening contains the following:

```
var iRegex = /android|(iP(hone|ad))/i;
if(iRegex.test(navigator.userAgent)){
 var url= "<...>" + window.location.hash;
 if(true) top.location=url; else window.location=url;
}
```

This JS redirects the parent page (your page [top window]) to another URL if the useragent matches android/iphone/ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it a linked static image. Otherwise you'd need to write a script to detect the location change attempt and override it. Besides, the iframe is messing with the framed page's analytics, counting each page view on your site as a view for the framed page.

Love the site by the way.